# United Premier member on a Continental flight operated by United

Tags: loyalty-programs, united-airlines

I am a silver premier member of United.  One good thing being a premier member of United is that I can enjoy Economy Plus seating.

I found a ticket issued by Continental, but operated by United. In this case, can I enjoy Economy Plus seating?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fly Continental pretty frequently, and to my knowledge they don't have anything called "Economy Plus". They do, however, have "Extra legroom" seats (which I believe is essentially the same thing).

United's [Elite benefits page](http://www.united.com/page/article/1,,53467,00.html?navSource=dropDown&linkTitle=elitebenefits) states as one of the benefits:

> Enjoy legroom with Economy Plus® seats on United and **extra
>   legroom/preferred seating on Continental**.

(emphasis mine)

With your United status, [Continental.com says](http://www.continental.com/CMS/en-US/products/travelproducts/Pages/ExtraLegroomSeats.aspx) you can reserve an extra legroom seat during the check-in process (not when you book your ticket) - if those seats are available:

> Extra legroom is currently available to our One Pass Elite members,
>   subject to availability. **Mileage Plus elite members may also reserve
>   an extra legroom seat, free of charge, during the check-in process**. In
>   addition, if it is available on your flight, customers may purchase
>   extra legroom seating anytime during the booking process, post-ticket
>   purchase or during check in.

If you book your ticket after January 1, 2012, you (as a Premier Silver member) will not be able to choose Economy Plus when you book your ticket on the new United, but the option [will be available to you at check-in](http://onepassmergerupdates.com/en/op/MileagePlusin2012/ProgramOverview). Beginning in January, you'll have to have Gold or higher status to choose economy plus for free when you book your ticket.